# how to check Foreach loop is working

Tags: php, foreach

Im very new to PHP coding.
 Just im getting values from object (class Project)and im iterating all object items to calculate duration of each project.

```
$projectDet = new Project();                    
$projectList = $projectDet->Find("name = ?",array($requ['name'] ));
if($projectList==false)
    return 0;
foreach($projectList as $proj)
{   
    $reportData = array();      
    $reportData[] = array("Project","TotalTime"); //Testing
    $key = $proj->id;
    $EstDUR[$key] = (strtotime($proj->Enddt) - strtotime($proj->Startdt));
}
return $reportData;
```

But reportData returns null even projectList is not null.

Comment: Which php framework are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that the array is `NULL` ? Try: `print_r($reportData);` Also you know that your array is a 2 dimensional array: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => "Project", [1] => "TotalTime"))`

Comment: You're redeclaring $reportData as a new `array()` at each iteration of the `foreach` loop. Take `$reportData = array ();` out of the loop. Also, change it to `$reportData = [];`

Comment: This will give you last record of reportData value. can you check using print_r($reportData); die(); before $key = $proj->id;

Comment: Please remove that `return 0;` statement, replace it with `$reportData = array(); if ($projectList) { foreach($projectList as $proj) { $reportData[] = 'some value'; } } return $reportData;` To ensure your code _always_ returns an array (consistency is important), and add some simple `var_dump` statements to debug (or better yet: install & learn to use Xdebug)

Answer (score 2):

Initate $reportData before foreach:

```
$reportData = array()
foreach($projectList as $proj) {   
    (..)
```